# Is misunderstanding the specification reason to downvote?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes

I am trying to understand why my question got downvoted in order to improve writing questions in the future (and/or improve the current one). I am also looking for guidance on how I should handle my question which has downvotes.

[How to make InvariantCulture recognize a comma as a decimal separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24375160/1)

### Reason for downvote

The main reason to the question was my misunderstanding of how `InvariantCulture` works and that it uses a fixed separator instead of a "anything goes".
My theory is that, due to the fact that I did not understand this detail and that the question is worded in a way that this should be true is the reason for the downvotes.

So basically, questions shouldn't mislead others of how the specification works.

Am I on the right path here?

### Next action

What should I do with my question? I am wondering because:
Due to the fact that it is getting downvotes I guess it has little value for the community. This leads me to believe that I should delete it.
There are two answers with upvotes that I don't want to remove, since they helped me. This leads me to believe that I should not delete it.

Comment: Well, the meta-effect is kicking-in so there you have your upvotes....

Comment: @rene well, upvotes is always fun, but the reason is more due to the fact that I am self critical -The answer to "Why is someone disliking what I asked?" kind of thing.

Comment: Ultimately we can't read the mind of the downvoters. I don't usually downvote a question *merely* due to a misconception on the part of the asker, and I doubt that many users do. However, some misconceptions can harm a question *to the point of* making it worthy of a downvote. (For instance there was a question recently on Meta that implied that comments can get downvotes in the same way answers can, but comments can't. Did the OP mean to ask about answers? The misconception made the question unclear.) I'm not seeing your misconception being so great that the question is unclear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is not much wrong with that question. I see three possible improvements:

- Make your question stand out (maybe put it already at the start and repeat it at the end).
- Add what you would have expected as outcome (clearly visible)
- Clear the bloated comment thread underneat it. Remove your own comments and flag the ones that are obsolete.

And [Lucas Trzesniewski](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3764814/lucas-trzesniewski) suggest a better title:

> How to make InvariantCulture recognize a comma as a decimal separator?

Keep in mind though that a couple of downvotes (that question was on +1/-2 when I arrived at it) is not a big-deal. Don't waste a lot of energy on it. Better spend it on answering some fun questions.

Comment: I'd add: provide a better title, since the current one doesn't really match the question contents. And the first paragraph is somewhat confusing, you should state up front what you expect. Right now, it's at the bottom of the post.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski hmm, I find the title OK-ish. How would you reword it?

Comment: Something along: *How to make InvariantCulture recognize a comma as a decimal separator?* The title isn't strictly bad, but I found it a bit confusing.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski yes, that was my reason for this meta post - since I thought that Single.Parse *should* parse it correctly, it felt to me that it ignored it. So my title was clear for me, i.e. to me it ignored the decimal point.